# WPF Frame animation to slide in/out pages is not working properly with data triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, mvvm

### Goal

With my application, I try to create a "single window"-application in WPF. Therefore the content of the frame (shown below) is set through data bindings. In order to animate this process i trigger the `AnimateFrameOutToLeft`- and `AnimateFrameInToLeft`- Properties out of the ViewModel. That should create the effect of new Pages "sliding" in or out.
Steps of the process of changing the frame's content (in the ViewModel):

1. `AnimateFrameOutToLeft = true; AnimateFrameOutToLeft = false;`
2. Change the content of the frame
3. `AnimateFrameInToLeft = true; AnimateFrameInToLeft = false;`

### Problem

In this order (regarding the data triggers) the animation of the page "sliding" is not shown. The opacity of the frame is 0.
With a changed order the animation of the page "sliding" out is not shown. Why is that so? And how can I solve this?

### Approaches

- I debugged the data triggers with custom attached properties: they are all fired correctly
- I debugged the animations (CompleteEvent) with custom attached properties: working as expected
- Changed the order of the data triggers: when `AnimateFrameOutToLeft` is fired for the second time it does not show the animation

**ShellView.xaml**

```xml
<Frame Margin="0" Background="White" Content="{Binding FrameContent, Mode=OneWay}" Focusable="False">
    <Frame.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimateFrameInToLeft}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="50,0,0,0" To="0" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimateFrameOutToLeft}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="0" To="0,0,50,0" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" FillBehavior="HoldEnd"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Frame.Style>
   ...
</Frame>
```

### Edit (Refering binding problems out of the ControlTemplate)

**ShellView.xaml**

```xml
<Window ...>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="{Binding KeyPressedCommand}" CommandParameter="Esc"/>
    <!-- this binding works -->
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Frame Margin="0" Background="White" Content="{Binding FrameContent, Mode=OneWay}" Focusable="False">
            <Frame.ContentTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                        <ContentControl.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                                <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <TranslateTransform/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.AnimateFrameToLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ShellView}}}"  Value="True">
                                <!-- this binding does not work -->
...
```

The AnimateFrameToLeft-Property is defined in the same class as the command above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous animation is blocking the following animation (or the animated properties) due to the `FillBehavior.HoldEnd`.

Another error is the way you manipulate the `Frame.Margin` property.
Note that if you want to slide out to the left your `ThicknessAnimation` should animate the `Margin` from `0` to `-50,0,0,0` (instead of `0,0,50,0`).
This is because a positive `FrameworkElement.Margin` only affects the surrounding elements and not the actual element. This means because there is no neighboring element to the right of the `Frame`, you don't see any effect (otherwise the right neighbor would be pushed to the right by 50 pixels).
To affect the `Frame`, you would have to use a *negative* `Margin` to "drag" it.
The recommended approach would be to animate a `TranslateTransform` instead of the margin's thickness.

Also note that animating the `Frame` itself may not be the best solution. If you show the navigation controls on the `Frame`, it would look quite odd to see everything moving in and out. You should animate the `Frame.Content` directly instead.

### Version 1 (recommended)

The `DataTrigger` is based on a property's state. It is triggered by a state change and executes the `DataTrigger.EnterActions`. Once the state falls back to the original state, the `DataTrigger.ExitActions` will be executed. The "property value lock" held by the enter animation (which uses `FillBehavior.HoldEnd`) will not affect the exit animation.
You should make use of the automatic state tracking by the `DataTrigger` and move the second slide-in animation to the `DataTrigger.ExitActions` collection.

In the following example the `Frame.ContentTemplate` is used to animate the content rather than the `Frame` itself. Instead of a `ThicknessAnimation` this example uses a `DoubleAnimation` to animate the frame's `ContentControl.RenderTransform` property (which is set to a `TranslateTransform`):

**Trigger the animation**

```
private async void ChangePage_OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // Slide current Frame.Content out to the left
  AnimateFrameOutToLeft = true;

  
  await Task.Delay(5000);

  // Slide new Frame.Content in from left to right left
  AnimateFrameOutToLeft = false;
}
```

**Animation definition**

```
<Frame x:Name="Frame" NavigationUIVisibility="Visible">
  <Frame.ContentTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
        <ContentControl.Style>
          <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
              <Setter.Value>
                <TranslateTransform />
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimateFrameOutToLeft}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)" 
                                       Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                       To="-50" 
                                       FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                       Duration="0:0:0.25" 
                                       From="1" To="0"
                                       FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                  <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                      <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                       Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                       To="0" 
                                       FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Duration="0:0:0.25" 
                                         From="0" To="1"
                                         FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
                    </Storyboard>
                  </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
      </ContentControl>
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
  </Frame.ContentTemplate>
</Frame>
```

### Version 2

The properties `Frame.Margin` and `Frame.Opacity` are still blocked by the previous animation which is still executing due to the `FillBehavior.HoldEnd` setting.
You have to stop the previous animation before executing the next in the timeline.

Give the starting `BeginStoryboard` a name e.g. `SlideOutStoryboard`. Then add a `StopStoryboard`, that targets the former `BeginStoryboard`, to the slide-in trigger's `EnterActions` collection:

```
<Frame.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Frame}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimateFrameOutToLeft}" Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
          <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SlideOutStoryboard">
            <Storyboard>
              <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                  From="0" To="-50,0,0,0" 
                                  FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
              <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                               From="1" To="0"
                               FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      </DataTrigger>

      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AnimateFrameInToLeft}" Value="True">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>

          <!-- Stop the previous BeginStoryBoard "SlideOutStoryboard" -->
          <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SlideOutStoryboard" />

          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
              <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" 
                                  From="-50,0,0,0" To="0,0,0,0" 
                                  FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
              <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.25" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                               From="0" To="1"
                               FillBehavior="HoldEnd" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Frame.Style>
```

### Version 3

This is an implementation that extends `Frame`. It is used like the standard `Frame` except that it automatically animates the `Content` on navigation (or `Content` change):

```
public class AnimatedFrame : Frame
{
  private bool IsAnimating { get; set; }
  private UIElement NextContent { get; set; }
  private UIElement PreviousContent { get; set; }
  private Action PreviousContentTransformCleanupDelegate { get; set; }
  private Action NextContentTransformCleanupDelegate { get; set; }

  public AnimatedFrame() => this.Navigating += OnNavigating;

  private void OnNavigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.IsAnimating 
      || !(e.Content is UIElement nextContent 
        && this.Content is UIElement))
    {
      return;
    }

    e.Cancel = true;
    this.PreviousContent = this.Content as UIElement;
    this.NextContent = nextContent;
    AnimateToNextContent();
  }

  private void AnimateToNextContent()
  {
    PrepareAnimation();
    StartPreviousContentAnimation();
  }

  private void PrepareAnimation()
  {
    this.IsAnimating = true;


    Transform originalPreviousContentTransform = this.PreviousContent.RenderTransform;
    this.PreviousContent.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
    this.PreviousContentTransformCleanupDelegate =
      () => this.PreviousContent.RenderTransform = originalPreviousContentTransform;


    Transform originalNextContentTransform = this.NextContent.RenderTransform;
    this.NextContent.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 0);
    this.NextContentTransformCleanupDelegate = () => this.NextContent.RenderTransform = originalNextContentTransform;
  }

  private void StartPreviousContentAnimation()
  {
    var unloadAnimation = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation slideOutAnimation = CreateSlideOutAnimation();
    unloadAnimation.Children.Add(slideOutAnimation);

    DoubleAnimation fadeOutAnimation = CreateFadeOutAnimation();
    unloadAnimation.Children.Add(fadeOutAnimation);
    unloadAnimation.Completed += StartNextContentAnimation_OnPreviousContentAnimationCompleted;

    unloadAnimation.Begin();
  }

  private void StartNextContentAnimation_OnPreviousContentAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.Content = this.NextContent;

    var loadAnimation = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimation slideInAnimation = CreateSlideInAnimation();
    loadAnimation.Children.Add(slideInAnimation);

    DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = CreateFadeInAnimation();
    loadAnimation.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);
    loadAnimation.Completed += Cleanup_OnAnimationsCompleted;

    loadAnimation.Begin();
  }

  private void Cleanup_OnAnimationsCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.PreviousContentTransformCleanupDelegate.Invoke();
    this.NextContentTransformCleanupDelegate.Invoke();
    this.IsAnimating = false;
  }

  private DoubleAnimation CreateFadeOutAnimation()
  {
    var fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd)
      {BeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero};
    Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeOutAnimation, this.PreviousContent);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOutAnimation, new PropertyPath(nameof(UIElement.Opacity)));
    return fadeOutAnimation;
  }

  private DoubleAnimation CreateSlideOutAnimation()
  {
    var slideOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(
        0,
        -50,
        new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)),
        FillBehavior.HoldEnd)
      {BeginTime = TimeSpan.Zero};

    Storyboard.SetTarget(slideOutAnimation, this.PreviousContent);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
      slideOutAnimation,
      new PropertyPath(
        $"{nameof(UIElement.RenderTransform)}.({nameof(TranslateTransform)}.{nameof(TranslateTransform.X)})"));
    return slideOutAnimation;
  }

  private DoubleAnimation CreateFadeInAnimation()
  {
    var fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeInAnimation, this.NextContent);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath(nameof(UIElement.Opacity)));
    return fadeInAnimation;
  }

  private DoubleAnimation CreateSlideInAnimation()
  {
    var slideInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(
      -50,
      0,
      new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)),
      FillBehavior.HoldEnd);

    Storyboard.SetTarget(slideInAnimation, this.NextContent);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
      slideInAnimation,
      new PropertyPath(
        $"{nameof(UIElement.RenderTransform)}.({nameof(TranslateTransform)}.{nameof(TranslateTransform.X)})"));
    return slideInAnimation;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have problems binding to the `AnimateFrameInToLeft`-Property. Is there a better solution than naming the window and accessing the property through `{Binding DataContext.AnimateFrameInToLeft, ElementName=name}`? I have already tried to use relative sources but that did not work.

Comment: This property is defined on MainWindow? Then use `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}, Path=AnimateFrameInToLeft}`.

Comment: The property is defined in the DataContext of the ShellView (the parent window). I tried this: `{Binding Path=AnimateFrameToLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ShellView}}}`. But the result still is this: `System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='ProjectNamespace.ShellView', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=AnimateFrameToLeft; DataItem=null; target element is 'ContentControl' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`

Comment: If this is the same `DataContext` as of the `Frame` you can use `{Binding AnimateFrameInToLeft}`. Otherwise you have to explicitely reference the `DataContext`: `{Binding Path=DataContext.AnimateFrameToLeft, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ShellView}}}`

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the problem is that the ShellView is not found because the DataItem (see above) is null. Your approach does not work either. Is this a problem because of the ContentControl? Do i have to set its DataContext somehow?

Comment: From what I can see from your example the Frame is a direct child of ShellView. Do the binding should be able to find it. It looks like the data context is not set. Can you please show how you initialize your ShellView? I had defined aDependencyProperty in the hosting control (MainWindow) and I had no issues. The animation worked well. Do I guess your initialisation is wrong. It's also important where exactly this property is defined!?

Comment: First of all thank you for your detailed help. I updated the question. As you can see the other bindings are all working perfectly. The DataContext is set through another instance of a "mediating" object at the creation of the View object . The whole trigger does only work if i apply a name to the Window and bind to that.

Comment: I have checked it and I can reproduce your issue. The error message you gave me indicates that the content of the `Frame.ContentTemplate` is not direct part of the visual tree. That's why the `Binding.RelativeSource` won't resolve. You have to reference the source by name. If this is absolutely not possible we can write a behavior or extend `Frame`. Up to you.

Comment: I think i will name the window and bind to it by its name. I was just curious wether there is a 'cleaner' solution. Again thank you for your detailed help.

Comment: I have added a third version. A quick implementation that derives from `Frame`. Animation is triggered automatically when you set new `Content` directly or using the `NavigationService`.